# Unable to pass the value of selected row of MVC kendo grid to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have implemented kendo grid , a right click context menu and also the select function which trigger when the user tries to select the context menu. I am trying to pass the values of certain columns when I select the edit context menu. I am getting the id and country code on the client side but my controller gets only the id. Not sure why countrycode is coming null.

Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.RequestViewModel>()
.Name("GridRequest")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(o => o.RequestID).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CountryCode).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.SalesOffice).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CustomerNumber).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProjectName).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProjectContent).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ContractStartDate).Width("140px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Priority).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.NameOfResponsiblePerson).Width("170px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Status).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedBy).Width("110px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate).Width("110px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ModifiedBy).Width("110px");
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()

.Selectable(selectable => selectable
    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
    .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .Events(events => events
    .Change("onChange")
)
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(t => t.RequestID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Requests_Read", "Request"))
    )
)
```

Context menu

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ContextMenu()
        .Name("RequestMenu")
        .Target("#GridRequest")
        .Filter("tr")
        .Orientation(ContextMenuOrientation.Vertical)
        .Animation(animation =>
        {
            animation.Open(open =>
            {
                open.Fade(FadeDirection.In);
                open.Duration(500);
            });
        })
         .Items(items =>
         {
             items.Add()
                 .Text("Edit").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "contextMenuItem" });

             items.Add()
                .Text("Update Status").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "contextMenuItem" });

         })
         .Events(e =>
         {
             e.Select("onSelect");

         })
    )
```

Javascript

```
function onSelect(e) {
        var grid = $("#GridTeam").data("kendoGrid");
        var requestId;

        switch ($(e.item).children(".k-link").text()) {

            case "Edit":
                var grid = $("#GridRequest").data("kendoGrid");
               // var column = grid.columns[0];
                var selectedBackup = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                requestId = selectedBackup.id;
                code = selectedBackup.CountryCode;

                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("EditRequest", "Request", new { id = "_id_", status="Edit", countryCode = "_code_" })'.replace('_id_', requestId).replace('_code_', code);
                break;
            case "Update Status":

                var statusWindow = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
                var grid = $("#GridRequest").data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); 
                id = selectedRow.id;
                name = selectedRow.ProjectName;
                code = selectedRow.CountryCode;
                statusWindow.refresh({ data: { requestId: id, projectName: name, countryCode: code } }).center().open();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 [Route("Request/AddRequest")]
        [Route("Request/EditRequest/{id?}")]
        public ActionResult NewRequest_Read(string id, string countryCode)
        {
            NewRequestViewModel newReqeustViewModel = new NewRequestViewModel();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                var result = requestRepository.GetRequesById(int.Parse(id));
                return View("NewRequestView", (Mapper.Map<NewRequestViewModel>(result)));
            }
            return View("NewRequestView", newReqeustViewModel);
        }
```

routedebugger output

[image]

route.config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Request", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Message",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Message", action = "Authorize", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
    }
```

Comment: Check your browser's network tab to see exactly how the URL is being formed when the request is sent to verify country code is sent. Then use Route debugger to see if it matches your route. Country code is not in your route so I think it needs to be generated as a query string parameter a la `?countryCode=`  UrlAction may not be doing this properly. Here is route debugger: https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/

Comment: I have done some changes. I dont need to pass the edit status. So i updated the url action to  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("EditRequest", "Request", new { id = "_id_",  countryCode = "_code_" })'.replace('_id_', requestId).replace('_code_', code);    and controller route to this         [Route("Request/EditRequest/{id}/{countryCode}")]

Comment: The url generated is http://localhost/CC.GRP.MCRequest/Request/EditRequest/21?countryCode=GB. Ideally it should be I think http://localhost/CC.GRP.MCRequest/Request/EditRequest/id=21/countryCode=GB

Comment: What is the best way of doing it ?

Comment: or it should be http://localhost/CC.GRP.MCRequest/Request/EditRequest/22/GB

Comment: That first URL *should* work as far as I can tell.  Try changing the route attribute to just `[Route("Request/EditRequest")]`  It will change how the URL is generated but be curious if that works. It *might* be redundant to define the `{id?}` param in the attribute since most MVC apps have a default route with `{id?}` already defined(depends on if you've change that in Startup config).  Beyond that if I were in your shoes I'd get the Route debugger setup. I'd recommend editing question and adding that you checked Network tab and post that URL you saw there. Maybe someone will catch a mistake.

Comment: I have updated the route to [Route("Request/EditRequest")] as per your suggestion. I have uploaded the screenshot of route debugger in the post. I am new to routedebugger and need help in inferring the results. That route doesnt work however

Comment: Added the routeconfig as well

Comment: I have added this new code         var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("EditRequest", "Request", new { id = "_id_", countryCode = "_code_"}))';
                var params = url.replace('_id_', requestId).replace('_code_', code);
                window.location.href = params;

Comment: I changed the route to  [Route("Request/EditRequest/{id}")] and it seems to work. Could you confirm if its correct ?

Comment: Yes that is fine if you are happy with the URL format. Maybe when you had an optional `?` param then it has to be the last one and it won't bind those after it.  Nice job figuring it out.

Comment: the url looks like this now http://localhost/CC.GRP.MCRequest/Request/EditRequest/78?countryCode=DE

Comment: I am not happy with the url format though. Any suggestions

Comment: Try `[Route("Request/EditRequest/{id}/{countryCode}")]` if you want `/EditRequest/1/GB`